# How do you test whether a tab is active with dojo tabs

Tags: javascript, dojo, tabcontainer, digit

How do you test whether a tab is active or not with a dojo tab container?   (In JQuery this is simple... you can use something like this

```
if($("#accordion").accordion('option', 'active') == mytabNumber){
```

With dojo's, dijit.layout.TabContainer  there must be a similiar way to do it without having to write a litener function and all that jazz.

perhaps something like...

```
if( dojo.byId("tab2"), {selected:true} ){
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can compare the widget for the tab with the tab container's `selectedChildWidget` property, i.e.:

`dijit.byId('tabContainer').selectedChildWidget == dijit.byId('tab2')`

Comment: Looks like .id is actually a property of the .selectedchildwidget object... so you can simplify this as...

dijit.byId('tabContainer').selectedChildWidget.id = "tab2"

Answer (score 2):

If you have a reference to the tab already, you can simply just check its 'selected' property to see if it's selected, regardless of the container it is in.

```
var tab2 = dijit.byId('tab2');
if (tab2.get('selected')) { /* do stuff */ }
```

I've created a more detailed example at http://jsfiddle.net/brianarn/ws28T/

Answer (score 0):

Here's  more complete code answer that gives the surrounding code for Dojo 1.8:

```
require(["dijit/registry",  "dojo/ready", "dojo/domReady!"], function (registry, ready) {
    ready(function () { //wait till dom is parsed into dijits
        if (dijit.byId('tabContainer').selectedChildWidget == dijit.byId('tab2'))
            alert('Yes, we found it!');
    });
});
```